# How to train a machine learning model if there is a relationship between two different data points?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

How to train a machine learning model if there is a relationship between two different data points? I mean not relationship between two variables among the point but that between two different data examples or points, so that i want to classify similar such set of datapoints into one single class . Which algorithm is most suited in this case . I want to write the algorithm on my own.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at **K Nearest Neighbours** algorithm.

Comment: try k-means, if you do not know the classes in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question and really depends on the type of data you have and how it is distributed.

There are many types of classifiers that you can use.
[This link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html), from scikit-learn shows you a comparison between many algorithms that could help you choose which one to pick.

I understand you want to write the algorithm yourself, but I would recommend you looking at [scikit-learn.org](http://scikit-learn.org) and trying out different algorithms. Once you have tried and wanted to implement yourself, you can have a look at blogs, [like this one](https://skratch.valentincalomme.com/learning-units/supervised/k-nearest-neighbours/), which explains in details the intrinsic works of models, like **k-nearest-neighbours** for example.